# User string containing MDDSJS

Tags: html

I have a website that submits a form but when in IE 8+, it submits it twice so it examines the user string to determine if it it needs to report an error.

I received an error today because the following was in the user string "MDDSJS;"

The full user sting was "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MDDSJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko".

I have searched for MDDSJS and all I can find is that it is in user strings but not what it means.

Does anyone know what "MDDSJS" part means?

Comment: I plugged this UA string into http://user-agent-string.info, and all it has to say about `MDDSJS` is "unknown"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had another look for what this and finally found that it is a OEM token for a Dell device

http://user-agents.me/windows-oem-manufacturer-list